# Disable TestNG for failsafe maven plugin, keep only for surefire

Tags: java, maven, junit, testng

I have mixed unit testing frameworks (for surefire maven plugin) in a project: JUnit + TestNG (almost all tests are JUnit tests but TestNG was included by [reactive-streams TCK](https://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-tck-1.0.3-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/tck/package-summary.html) framework, which is required for two tests. All integration tests (failsafe) are only JUnit tests. I managed to configure surefire to run both tests: JUnit and TestNG with this plugin configuration:

```xml
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire.version}</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.2</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>surefire-testng</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skip>false</skip>
              <includes>
                <include><!-- test one --></include>
                <include><!-- test two --></include>
              </includes>
              <junitArtifactName>none:none</junitArtifactName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>surefire-junit</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skip>false</skip>
              <excludes>
                <exclude><!-- test one --></exclude>
                <exclude><!-- test two --></exclude>
              </excludes>
              <testNGArtifactName>none:none</testNGArtifactName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

And this config is working fine, when I run `mvn test` Maven run surefire tests.

But when I try to run `mvn verify` to check failsafe tests, Maven fails with error:

```
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireExecutionException: Exception in provider
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:91)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1198)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1063)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:889)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.testng.xml.XmlSuite.setParallel(java.lang.String)'
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNGMapConfigurator.configure(TestNGMapConfigurator.java:71)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG510Configurator.configure(TestNG510Configurator.java:40)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:110)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:146)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:186)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:161)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:84)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:87)
[ERROR]     ... 25 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

The full source code and plugin configuration is available here: https://github.com/artipie/http/tree/multipart

What is the correct way to disable TestNG in failsafe plugin and keep it only in surefire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually forcefully specify the provider Junit to `maven-failsafe-plugin` and then remove the `testng` from the global dependencies tag

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <!-- <parallel>none</parallel> -->
      <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I don't really want to disable failsafe plugin completely, there are a lot of JUnit integration tests in failsafe.

Comment: @Kirill Can you the way by removing testng from dependencies tag and manually specify `surefire-junit`  to failsafe??

Comment: Thanks, please update the answer with your latest comment, and I'll accept it